# Problem finding array entry based on object attribute

Tags: python, arrays, class, indexing

i have been having problems with a function useing an object as an input, but not knowing the position of the object, so i have made a stripped down version of the code to exemplyfi

```
sett = []


class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.num = num

    @staticmethod
    def howmany(who):
        print(who.number)


sett.append(Test('dog', 2))
sett.append(Test('cat', 5))
sett.append(Test('fish', 7))
Test.howmany(sett.index(Test.name == 'dog'))
```

if it worked at intended this would output '2' as that is the number of the object with name 'dog'.

pleas help thanks

Comment: You're alternating between `num` and `number` so currently your code crashes. Can you fix that please?

Comment: Also, do you really want to find the index or the `Test` object? Because even if `index` worked with the argument you are passing, you'd still get an *integer* that you would pass to `Test.howmany`.

Comment: Please don't fix your question based on answers. Otherwise the answer(s) don't make sense any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a mix up between `num` and `number`. Besides that necessary fix, the `index` method returns ... an index, not a member of `sett`. Moreover, `Test.name` is wrong: `Test` is your class object, not an instance. You could use the `next` function to get a matching item.

As a side note: you can just create the list of three items in one go. There is no reason to call `append` repeatedly:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, name, number):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number  # fix

    @staticmethod
    def howmany(who):
        print(who.number)

sett = [Test('dog', 2), Test('cat', 5), Test('fish', 7)]
Test.howmany(next(test for test in sett if test.name == 'dog'))
```

Another note: it is not clear to me why you want to define `howmany` as a static method and not as an instance method, unless you would foresee that `who` could be `None`, but that logic is currently missing.